# Twilio Coverage and Testing

Tags: twilio

1. Coverage
   We are building an app that needs to send SMS and VOICE. We start with US, but we will be adding more countries soon and the list of countries will grow and grow.
   With an US number do we have the whole world covered for voice and sms?
2. Testing
   When we test the application with the Test credentials can we actually send sms and calls?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This isn't really the place to ask questions like that, it's more of a place for help with programming.

However, in answer to your questions:

1. You can make calls and send SMS messages all over the world with just one US Twilio number. However, you will likely find that localising that number is a better user experience for those in other countries. There are also considerations of per number messaging limits that some carriers impose (in the US in particular, you should not send more than 200 messages per day on a single number to avoid being flagged as spam by the carriers, see [the guidelines here](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/us)
2. When you use Test credentials Twilio will respond as if a message or call has been created, but will not actually send them. To receive calls and messages from your API requests you should use the production credentials.